# I can't access my wallet at Bitknock cloud mining anymore

Tags: wallet, lost-bitcoins, recover-private-key, cloud-mining

I was doing mining with Bitknock but they closed the website without informing us.

I can't access my wallet. Here is my wallet address

```
fnwg643zjnfwsqks
```

What must I do now? Should I acknowledge that I lost my Bitcoins?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, most of the "*cloud mining*" websites are ponzi schemes trying to disguise themselves as a cloud mining contract provider.

[This site](http://kipicommunity.org/what-is-bitknock/) catagorizes Bitknock as a ponzi/scam dated back to November 2015. A little bit research could have made you aware of the dangers.

I personally lost dozens of bitcoin in such projects, even if I joined only the most secure looking. General rule of thumb: If it looks too good to be true, don't buy it.